# Mariadb and "SSL connection error: unknown error number"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

I'm trying to setup ubuntu 14.04 and Mariadb (5.5.56-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) with SSL. I've configured according to the instructions [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/)

My server reports this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                            |
| have_ssl      | YES                            |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath    |                                |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA             |
| ssl_key       | /etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

When I connect from a client outfitted with the new certs, I get the message: `SSL connection error: unknown error number`

A tcpdump on the server shows the server cert being passed to the client then a few very short packets later, the server sends `08S01Bad handshake` to the client.

Some searching turned up a [mysql workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197399/ssl-connection-error-unknown-error-number/43207082#43207082) error, but not sure it's related. Same error message though. Anyone know where else to look to fix this? The logs in `/var/log/*` or `/var/log/mysql/*` seem to be void of any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it. Looks like server and client certs cannot have the same `CN:` https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68500

I was using an `openssl.cnf` with default values loaded so all certs used the same `CN`